# Can any .md file be set to autodisplay in a github repo the way that a README file does?

Tags: r, github, knitr

If I render my .Rmd output as a github_document it saves as an .md file. I would like this .md file to automaticall display way that a README.md file does in github. This would highlight the actual output of my analysis, but I am unsure of how to make .md files autodisplay when they are not README files.

Comment: Are you looking to have your `.md` file display at the root of the repo, or are you looking to have it display like the README does once it's selected?

Comment: I'd like the .md report to be on full display below the file names in the repo the way that a README.md displays.

Comment: Only the README is displayed at the root of the repo. You can either link to other `.md` files or you can include their content in the README.

Comment: Each directory can have its own README which is displayed below the contents of that directory. [Here's an example](https://github.com/methvind/readme).

Comment: In the meantime I have renamed my central report output as README.md, and it displays as I want. I was just wondering if there was a way to make .md files with other names autodisplay at the root.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Here's the [Github README documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-readmes) if you want to know more.

Comment: Awesome discussion and salient points, @DakotaMethvin, I suggest you aggregate your comments into an answer. (I think that's the only answer that can be made here, since I agree that I believe github does not support other file names for that view.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments on the question:

Are you looking to have your `.md` file display at the root of the repo, or are you looking to have it display like the `README` does once it's selected?

> I'd like the .md report to be on full display below the file names in the repo the way that a README.md displays.

Only the `README` is displayed at the root of the repo. You can either link to other `.md` files or you can include their content in the `README`.

Each directory can have its own `README` which is displayed below the contents of that directory. [Here's an example](https://github.com/methvind/readme).

> I was just wondering if there was a way to make .md files with other names autodisplay at the root.

Not that I'm aware of. Here's the [Github README documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-readmes) if you want to know more.